# Set the Webform-CiviCRM Contribution Amount to a parameter value

Tags: webform-civicrm, contributions

A client is using webform-CiviCRM for a contribution page.  Due to pro-rating and other factors, each contributor needs to pay a unique amount - and thus the webform has the exposed "Contribution Amount" element that can accept an amount from a user.

How can I pre-fill this Contribution Amount using a custom field value?  The webform Default Value can't be set to a token for a custom field that has the amount (returns "This is a CiviCRM currency field. Default value must be a number.", even if the field is an integer or a number.

It might also be possible to attach the $ amount to the URL as a parameter?

Answer (score 3):

Just adding to this -> this is now possible (since today: many thanks for Fuzion for re-asking this question and helping to see it through!); we had to relax a form_error that was preventing tokens to be injected in the default field for
contribution_total_amount;

You can now do:

```
/webform-civicrm-example?civicrm_1_contribution_1_contribution_total_amount=120
```

and if you have configured your Contribution Amount -> default as:

```
[current-page:query:civicrm_1_contribution_1_contribution_total_amount]
```

Then it will fetch that $120 -> and give you:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add the value in a URL to prefill it (if that is what you are asking). If the URL is: `/paymentform`

I think you could then send a URL such as `/paymentform?amount=25` with a default value in the amount field of `[current-page:query:amount]`

*Aside:* If you are sending these URLs from a CiviMail mailing (or sending an email to a contact through CiviCRM) and have the amount information in a custom field, you could prefill the `amount` value in the URL [via a token](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/237/26) for that custom field value.