# Membership Receipts from Civi webform for On Behalf of Organisation

Tags: civicontribute, webform-civicrm

(Civi 4.4.6, Civi Webform 7.x.4-10, Drupal 7.37)

From what I read on the Civi webform wiki (https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Webform+CiviCRM+Integration), receipts should be generated from the attached contribution page just as they would from the contribution page itself.  Is this not correct?  What is happening with our client's is that none of the usual info about the organization for whom the user is joining/renewing is included in the email, so when the organization gets the copy of the receipt, there's nothing to identify who it was (other than, of course, the email address).  Is there some trick to passing all the necessary information over?

Here is the image (identifying info awkwardly scribbled out - graphic artist, I am not): 
[image]

Comment: Have you modified your receipt templates in CiviCRM ?

Comment: No, we have not modified the receipt template.  From the documentation it doesn't seem that one should _have_ to do so - the same information that would appear in the receipt from the regular contribution page should also appear in the receipt from the webform.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need to manually add tokens to the receipt - message template  - so you can provide more information to the receipt -

Creating new tokens - https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Tokens

if you need to add some contact tokens then refer to the below - 
[Can I put custom field tokens into a message template?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/226/can-i-put-custom-field-tokens-into-a-message-template)

I guess this helps !!!

Comment: Thanks, but the information should already be in the receipt template.  It was appearing correctly when the contribution page was used outside of the webform, so I'm not sure why it's not appearing now.

Comment: Both are different templates - please look for Administer -> Communications -> Message Template -> system Workflow Messages. so, you will get a better idea. - Thanks

Comment: Yes, I am well familiar with the membership receipt templates and have modified them on numerous occasions - but in this case, the client's system workflow receipt templates are all straight out of the box;  none have been edited.  Again, if the webform is using the membership receipt template, I should not _need_ to customize it.  Is the webform in fact using the contribution receipt template?  (which would be odd)

Comment: I have not tested it But it would be using contribution template because we do need a contribution page for an webform configuration - need to test

Comment: Hmm - that seems like an unfortunate circumstance.  Since Civi uses contribution pages for both contributions and memberships, and can discern between the two for receipting purposes, I would have hoped that Civi webform would be able to use similar functionality.

Comment: From my own testing it does seem like it's using the correct receipt template but some of the information is clearly getting lost between being recorded on the contact record (which happens correctly and completely) and generating the receipt.

Comment: I will run a quick test by tomorrow and will let u know the status

Comment: We've done some additional investigation.  Firstly, the webform is indeed using the contribution email template, not the membership one.  This particular membership is for an organization, but what is happening is that the membership is getting applied to the org (correct) but the payment is getting applied to the primary contact (incorrect).  No email gets sent re the membership.  We were hoping to replicate the "on behalf of organization" functionality of the Civi contribution page - that seems to be problematic.

Comment: was there any point checking if you could make the Org 'contact 1' on the form? I can see lots of reasons why that wouldn't be useful in many circumstances

Comment: Is your civi version above correct "Civi 4.4.6," - if so that's pretty old &  probably everyone commenting is basing their expectations on a recent release